# Use JavaScript and Bootstrap Segmented Buttons to change form action and input values on dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to build a form to submit a query to different search engines like Google, Bing etc. ... 
I came across bootstrap segmented buttons and now I wonder if it's possible to set the action (the search engine), name, placeholder and possible hidden inputs through these segmented buttons before the form gets submitted through the search button.

It should work in both ways:

Type in query -> set search engine through dropdown -> hit the search button to submit
Set search engine through dropdown -> Type in query -> hit the search button to submit

My html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/lumen/bootstrap.min.css"-->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Optional: Include the jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional: Incorporate the Bootstrap JavaScript plugins -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"-->
</head>
<body>



    <form id="search" name="search" class="bs-example bs-example-form" onreturn="setSubmit()" action="" role="form" method="" target="_blank">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DuckDuckGo" name="q" type="text" maxlength="255" value="">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
                    <button tabindex="-1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                        <li><a onclick="setSubmitDuckDuckGo()">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="setSubmitGoogle()">Another action</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Now I know, I need JS to change the values mentioned above. This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setSubmitDuckDuckGo() {
        $('#search').attr('target','_blank')
        $('#search').attr('action','https://www.duckduckgo.com/')
        $('#search').submit()

        function setSubmitGoogle() {
            $('#search').attr('target','_blank')
            $('#search').attr('action','https://www.google.com/')
            $('#search').submit() 
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope somebody can give me hint and show me how this can be done.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: **It's possible.**

Javascript `onclick` doesn't work in this case. Better use `href="#"`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">DuckDuckGo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for this.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setupForm($(this).text());
});
```

I've done a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vooL2h30/3/) for you with implemented `setupForm()`, where you can set action, placeholder, hidden inputs and more.